# How to update a text into a Label?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-native-app

I'm developing a Tizen native app for a watch face.

I created the base gui using the default create_base_gui function:

```
typedef struct appdata {
    Evas_Object *win;
    Evas_Object *conform;
    Evas_Object *label;
    Evas_Object *box;
} appdata_s;

static void
create_base_gui(appdata_s *ad, int width, int height)
{
    int ret;
    watch_time_h watch_time = NULL;

    /* Window */
    ret = watch_app_get_elm_win(&ad->win);
    if (ret != APP_ERROR_NONE) {
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "failed to get window. err = %d", ret);
        return;
    }

    evas_object_resize(ad->win, width, height);

    /* Conformant */
    ad->conform = elm_conformant_add(ad->win);
    evas_object_size_hint_weight_set(ad->conform, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND, EVAS_HINT_EXPAND);
    elm_win_resize_object_add(ad->win, ad->conform);

    /* Box */
    ad->box = elm_box_add(ad->conform);
    evas_object_show(ad->box);
    elm_object_content_set(ad->conform, ad->box);

    ad->label = elm_label_add(ad->box);
    evas_object_size_hint_align_set(ad->label, 0.5, 0.5);
    elm_object_text_set(ad->label, "Time");
    evas_object_show(ad->label);
    elm_box_pack_end(ad->box, ad->label);

    ret = watch_time_get_current_time(&watch_time);
    if (ret != APP_ERROR_NONE)
        dlog_print(DLOG_ERROR, LOG_TAG, "failed to get current time. err = %d", ret);

    update_watch(ad, watch_time, 0);
    watch_time_delete(watch_time);

    /* Show window after base gui is set up */
    evas_object_show(ad->win);
}
```

In the update_watch function I'm trying to update the text using this code:

```
static void
update_watch(appdata_s *ad, watch_time_h watch_time, int ambient)
{
    char watch_text[TEXT_BUF_SIZE];
    int hour24, minute, second;
    int time;

    if (watch_time == NULL)
        return;

    watch_time_get_hour24(watch_time, &hour24);
    watch_time_get_minute(watch_time, &minute);
    watch_time_get_second(watch_time, &second);

    elm_object_text_set(ad->label, "Update" );
}
```

But it does not work.

What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

at the first.
You miss a `evas_object_show(ad->conform);`
It makes invisible controls under conform. (box and label.)

And if your update watch function not work in every time, make it is called in `time_tick` callback in `watch_app_lifecycle_callback_s` structure.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot put in the post all the code.

There is also the function app_time_tick.

I pasted only the modified code.

Comment: how to your code not working? is controls not shown? or text is not changed? in your code, you set "Update" static string to label. of course it's not changing.

Comment: I think code is not bad. could you try remove old installed package and reinstall newer package. and reboot your device or emulator?